# What would cause files being added to a zip file to not be included in the zip?

Tags: c#, xml, zip

I work with a program that takes large amounts of data, turns the data into xml files, then takes those xml files and zips them for use in another program. Occasionally, during the zipping process, one or two xml files gets left out. It is fairly rare, once or twice a month, but when it does happen it's a big mess. I am looking for help figuring out why the files don't get zipped and how to prevent it. This code is straightforward:

```
public string AddToZip(string outfile, string toCompress)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(toCompress)) throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find the file to compress", toCompress);


        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(outfile);
        if(!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }

        // The program that gets this data can't handle files over 
        // 20 MB, so it splits it up into two or more files if it hits the 
        // limit.
        if (File.Exists(outfile))
        {
            FileInfo tooBig = new FileInfo(outfile);
            int converter = 1024;
            float fileSize = tooBig.Length / converter; //bytes to KB
            fileSize = fileSize / converter;  //KB to MB

            int limit = CommonTypes.Helpers.ConfigHelper.GetConfigEntryInt("zipLimit", "19");
            if (fileSize >= limit)
            {
                outfile = MakeNewName(outfile);
            }
        }

        using (ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(outfile))
        {
            zf.AddFile(toCompress,"");
            zf.Save();
        }

        return outfile;          
    }
```

Ultimately, what I want to do is have a check that sees if any xml files weren't added to the zip after the zip file is created, but stopping the problem in its tracks are best overall. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you *certain* that every file to be added gets passed to `AddToZip`? I suspect that the problem isn't with your `AddToZip` method, but rather with the code that calls `AddToZip`. What if the "missing files" were missing from the source directory? What if they had no data in them? You should add some logging to your code so that it outputs the `toCompress` file name on entry: "Adding file foo.xml..."

Comment: All of the xml files go into a folder and from there they are zipped up. I can see that the file is made, just sometimes gets missed in the zip process. I know that the program needs logging. There is a separate process that can tell if the file has bad data and that kicks it out and sends notification that it happened, so that is expected. I have inherited this monster and i'm trying to figure it out at the same time clean it up.

Comment: I can see three possibilities. Ordered by likelihood: 1) `AddToZip` never gets called for those "missing" files; 2) `AddToZip` throws an exception which is caught but not reported; 3) `AddToZip` succeeds, but somehow the file wasn't added. Is it possible that the XML file is created after the call that gets the list of files to zip up?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have that code inside a try... catch statement. Also make sure that if you have done that, you do something with the exception. It would not be the first case that has this type of exception handling:

```
try
{
     //...
}
catch { }
```

Given the code above if you have any exception on your process, you will never notice.

Comment: I will fix that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to judge from this function alone, here's a list of things that can go wrong:
- The toCompress file can be gone by the time zf.AddFile is called (but after the Exists test). Test return value or add exception handling to detect this.
- The zip outFile can be just below the size limit, adding a new file can make it go over the limit.
- The AddToZip() may be called concurrently, that may cause adding to fail.

How is the toCompress file remove handled? I think adding locking to the AddoZip() on a function scope might also be a good idea.

Comment: I don't think there is a remove written in. I will look into your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This could be a timing issue. You are checking to see if outfile is too big before trying to add the toCompress file. What you should be doing is:

1. Add toCompress to outfile
2. Check to see if adding the file made outfile too big
3. If outfile is now too big, remove toCompress, create new outfile, add toCompress to new outfile.

I suspect that you occasionally have an outfile that is just under the limit, but adding toCompress puts it over. Then the receiving program does not process outfile because it is too big.

I could be completely off base, but it is something to check.

Comment: I also believe that this can be rewritten in a better way. I will try it.